# FILTER() function where values exist in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Let "serviceRendered" named range be a column of values where there are multiple "services" inside the cell separated by commas. Example: "Bus passes, Food Service" OR "Food Service, Action Planning" etc.

Let "ListOfServices" be a named range that contains each service down the column. So A2 = "Bus Passes", A3 = "Food Service" etc.

This is the current formula.

```
=filter(serviceRendered, serviceRendered <> "", serviceRendered <> "N/A")
```

But somewhere in that formula I want to add:

```
, serviceRendered exists in ListOfServices.
```

To be even more specific, I want each word inside the cells in serviceRendered to EXIST inside the listOfServices range. So if there is a cell inside serviceRendered that says "Food Service, Bus Passes", I want the formula to pull that because "Food Service" and "Bus Passes" exist in the listOfServices range.

Comment: Could you share a copy of your spreadsheets for a better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=FILTER(serviceRendered, 
        serviceRendered <> "", 
        serviceRendered <> "N/A", 
        REGEXMATCH(LOWER(serviceRendered), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(ListOfServices))))
```

Comment: This is much closer to the solution! However, when I input into serviceRendered-- say "Food Service, oiewfhioewbf" the Filter() will still pull the entire value even though "oiewfhioewbf" is not a service inside listOfServices. So this solution seems to rely on the first word to exist inside listOfServices but doesn't care about the other words that come after.

Comment: @WilliamToscano can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Hello! So sorry for late reply on this but I have posted a question similar to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981517/if-cell-contains-a-string-listed-in-range                                             I shared a copy of a sheet and took a screenshot. I appreciate your time if you can answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correct (which is admittedly difficult without any spreadsheet, data or layout to look at), this may be what you're after:

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(serviceRendered,MMULT(1*NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SPLIT(serviceRendered,",")),ListOfServices,1,FALSE))),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(serviceRendered,",")),1,1,0))=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(serviceRendered,"[^,]",""))+1))`