# If cell contains a string listed in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Trying to output "True" if a cell contains a string listed in a range. See screenshot. This is a simplidied version of an old question I posted here [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358314/filter-function-where-values-exist-in-a-range)

Here is a [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wU0qg6YVijiP3XJ0ZFZvVXOKNH8eli9-ejRI8rYuayw/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your situation, for example, when a cell "D3" is checked in your showing image, you want to search using the values of all cells "C3:C". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Correct! Basically check if the cell in D3 contains an item inside the range C3:C

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample formula as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- For example, when a cell "D3" is checked in your showing image, you want to search using the values of all cells "C3:C".

In this case, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D3:D<>"",REGEXMATCH(D3:D,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,C3:C)),""))
```

- In this formula, the values of "C3:C" are used as the regex.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

Comment: Your answer worked! I also found another solution and I posted an answer to my own question. Let me know what you think

Comment: @William Toscano Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that there are various answers to achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF($D3="",,NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER($D3),JOIN("|",FILTER(LOWER($C$3:$C),$C$3:$C<>""))))))
```

I found this answer to my question based off of this [old question.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151160/check-if-google-sheet-cell-contains-string-from-range-of-cells)

[image]